# I have data from mysql and have converted to JSON incorrectly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, json

I have the following table:

```
-> +-----+---------+-----+-------+--------------+
-> | id1 | fname   | id2 | fname | relationship |
-> +-----+---------+-----+-------+--------------+
-> |   4 | Albaraa |   5 | Sadi  | Father       |
-> +-----+---------+-----+-------+--------------+
```

I assign the following to the variable $relations:

```
$relations = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Finally I print out the JSON encode of this variable using this:

```
echo json_encode($relations);
```

...and I get the following output:

```
[{"id1":"4","fname":"Sadi","id2":"5","relationship":"Father"}]
```

So here is a few questions about the output that I get:

1) You can see that my output does not seem right as it should be something like this:

```
[{"id1":"4","fname":"Albaraa","id2":"5","fname":"Sadi","relationship":"Father"}]
```

Why is it not printing correctly, does it have something to do with the fact that the table, has two columns with the same name "fname"? If there is any input on how to fix this that would be amazing!

2) Another thing I was curious to know is that I actually want to change the JSON to where it becomes something like this:

```
[{"id":"4","name":"Albaraa","id":"5","name":"Sadi","relationship":"Father"}]
```

Is there an easy way to change "id1" and "id2" to become "id" and both "fname" to become just "name"?

Again any input on this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) `fname` was overwritten. Try use different aliases in SQL query for matching fields.

2) You should not pass exact name matching properties. They might be overwitten by JSON-decoder. Better to pass them as a different JSON-parts.

```
[{"id":"4","name":"Albaraa","id":"5","name":"Sadi","relationship":"Father"}]
```

Should be like:

```
{
    "person1":{"id":4,"name":"Albaraa"},
    "person2":{"id":5,"name":"Sadi"},
    "relationship":"Father"
}
```

---

**UPDv1:**

For result:

```
-> +-----+---------+-----+--------+--------------+
-> | id1 | fname1  | id2 | fname2 | relationship |
-> +-----+---------+-----+--------+--------------+
-> |   4 | Albaraa |   5 | Sadi   | Father       |
-> +-----+---------+-----+--------+--------------+
```

Try to convert like this:

```
<?php
// $row is sql fetched row.

$person1  = array('id' => $row['id1'], 'name' => $row['fname1']);
$person2  = array('id' => $row['id2'], 'name' => $row['fname2']);
$response = array(
     'person1' => $person1,
     'person2' => $person2,
     'relationship' => $row['relationship']
);

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured that is what it was and I set an alias and the output worked! Now hopefully there'll be a way to change the JSON to where I need them in my 2nd question!

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll see what I can do with that, thanks for the amazing help!

Comment: I've tried it but...it is actually giving me the following error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW and that is on the $person1 line

Comment: @user1748026 for `$row = array('id1' => 4, 'fname1' => 'Albaraa', 'id2' => 5, 'fname2' => 'Sadi', 'relationship' => 'Father');` works fine. Shows: `{"person1":{"id":4,"name":"Albaraa"},"person2":{"id":5,"name":"Sadi"},"relationship":"Father"}`. Check your syntax.